# Can I insert a phpBB Forum into a Magento CMS Static Page or Block?

Tags: magento, phpbb, forums

I'm sure there is a much simpler solution for what I am trying to do here, but I am running out of ideas.  Essentially I need to create a phpBB forum what exists within my Magento install so that the header and footer from my Magento store are always visible.

The thought is to use a CMS static page for the forum and then style it accordingly. Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do without significant modification?  Or, do I just create a one off .phtml file that calls my header, footer and forum?  Am I on the right page or am I over/under thinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get around Magento's bootstrap (`/index.php`), because phpBB won't function if Magento is intercepting every URL.

There's also the issue of Magento and phpBB not sharing authentication systems, so users have to log into one, neither, or both. That's not a great UX if you ask me, but solving that problem is a very complicated issue.

Other than that you shouldn't have many problems.